# Слияние png изображений

Tags: php

Что нужно поменять в данном коде, чтоб картинка 156.png была слева а не внизу? Заранее благодарен.

```
$top_file = 'test.png'; 
$bottom_file = '156.png';
 $top = imagecreatefrompng($top_file);
  $bottom = imagecreatefrompng($bottom_file); 
 //get current width/height
  list($top_width, $top_height) = getimagesize($top_file);
 list($bottom_width, $bottom_height) = getimagesize($bottom_file); 
 // compute new width/height 
 $new_width = ($top_width > $bottom_width) ? $top_width : $bottom_width;
  $new_height = $top_height + $bottom_height; 
 // create new image and merge
  $new = imagecreate($new_width, $new_height); 
  imagecopy($new, $top, 0, 0, 0, 0, $top_width, $top_height); 

  imagecopy($new, $bottom, 0, $top_height+1, 0, 0, $bottom_width, $bottom_height);
   // save to file
  imagepng($new, 'merged_image.png');
```

Comment: При чем тут тег javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить строки:

```
...

// compute new width/height
$new_width = $top_width + $bottom_width;
$new_height = max($top_height, $bottom_height);
// create new image and merge
$new = imagecreate($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopy($new, $bottom, 0, 0, 0, 0, $bottom_width, $bottom_height);
imagecopy($new, $top, $bottom_width+1, 0, 0, 0, $top_width, $top_height);

...
```

Comment: слева всё тёмная область

Comment: если такуюже картинку добавить 'test.png'; то нормально видно, а  '156.png'; шире но по высоте уже

Comment: у меня две картинки чб, я покрасил 156 в яркий цвет, она растенулась

Comment: $img = imagecreatefrompng('156.png'); //создаем изображение из картинки
$white = imagecolorallocate($img,255,255,255); //определяем белый цвет
imagecolortransparent($img,$white); //делаем белый цвет прозрачным
imagepng($img,'156-1.png');
$bottom_file = '156-1.png';